# Changing from object oriented to procedural in PHP

Tags: php

I'm making a `PHP` page that connects to a database and it does connect to it great, but I want to change it from object oriented programming to procedural programming. The lines in the code that I want to change is `$result = $conn->query("select * from user where usernam' ".$username."' ");` and `if($result->num_rows>0)`. I've done some research online and I've found is [here](http://markonphp.com/simple-select-mysqli-php/).

Comment: You can use mysqli functions but I truly recommand you to keep using PDO and OO style, which are more and more common and used.

Comment: @Aurel thanks, I was just wondering how I would change between OO and procedural in case I got one and had to swap it to the other

Comment: You'd be better converting the code to use prepared statements/bind variables than converting it from OO to procedural

Comment: Off topic, but a note about your query string: I see that you're building it by concatenating the strings. If you do it this way, please make sure you've properly escaped the variables (ie `$username` in this case). Your example doesn't show you doing this. Alternatively, you can use the "Prepared Statement" functionality in either mysqli or PDO which is a better way of getting variables into the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving from object oriented programming to procedural programming is like going from 21st century to stone age world. My advice is, keep the object oriented pattern as it is.

But having said that, if you really want the procedural way, then change

```
$result = $conn->query("select * from user where usernam = '".$username."'");
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from user where usernam = '".$username."'");
```

and change

```
if($result->num_rows>0)
```

to

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

Comment: Did you check that he was connecting with `mysqli_`, because if he is using `PDO` this of course is not going to work

Comment: @RiggsFolly OP has shared a [tutorial](http://markonphp.com/simple-select-mysqli-php/) which is based on `mysqli` extension, so I guess OP is trying to use `mysqli`.